Quantile of the average of dependent Uniform[0, 1] variables
Let $X_1,\ldots,X_K$ be possibly dependent random variables that are marginally $\mathrm{Uniform}[0,1]$ distributed, and define $\bar X := \frac{1}{K}\sum_{i=1}^K X_i$.  Is it possible for the $\gamma$-quantile of $\bar X$ to be smaller than $\gamma$, for some $\gamma<1/2$?
We can see that $\bar X$ "should not have a heavier tail", in the sense that $E(\bar X-\frac{1}{2})^k \le E(X_1-\frac{1}{2})^k$; and that its $\gamma$-quantile must be $\ge \gamma/2$.  But I cannot prove or disprove the above claim.

At least for $K$ even, the $\gamma$-quantile can indeed get all the way down to $\gamma/2$. (Whether it can be exactly $\gamma/2$ depends on your definitions I think.)
For the extreme case, let $U$ be Uniform[$0,1$], and let
$$
V=
\begin{cases}
\gamma-U,&U\leq\gamma\\
1+\gamma-U, &U>\gamma.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $V$ is also Uniform[$0,1$], and $(U+V)/2$ takes value $\gamma/2$ with probability $\gamma$, and value $(1+\gamma)/2$ with probability $1-\gamma$.
If you now let $X_i=U$ for each odd $i$ and $X_i=V$ for each even $i$, then also $\bar{X}_K:=\frac{1}{K}\sum_{i=1}^K X_i=(U+V)/2$ for each positive even $K$.
I haven't thought through what the optimal value is in the case of $K$ odd!
